# Assign value from [0], [1], ... to Key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  float(273)
  [1]=>
  float(376)
}
```

i tried to `$IDs = array_flip($params);`, but the var_dump of `$IDs` is `NULL`

The Reason is to filter a huge List of Items with this IDs.

Comment: your array is $params ?

Comment: It is not clear what output do you expect. Please, add it to the question.

Comment: It is always a good idea to show us what output you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, because PHP arrays can have string and integer keys only. You have floats. If you would have integers, it's possible:

```
$arr = array_flip($arr);

array(2) {
    [273]=>
    int(0)
    [376]=>
    int(1)
}
```

Values can be quickly checked with [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
var_dump(isset($arr[273])); // bool(true)
```

Comment: thank you! I didnt concerned that only strings and integers are allowed as keys. Now i used JRequest::getInt to build the array from my url, array_flip worked after that.

Comment: That's the way to go (and the reason for why I didn't propose float to int conversion).